# Difference between panazep and lupizep

Tags: psychiatry, medication

When panazep did not work to reduce anxiety in me the psychiatrist prescribed lupizep. Since both contained the same ingredients Paroxetine and Clonazepam in the same amount I asked the doctor about the difference between them but he could not tell much about it. All he said was that in lupizep the molecules were joined with another technology. Can some one give a detailed answer please ? Thanks